# Help stopping a SharePoint Workflow with JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

I'm attempting to write a script that will cancel and start workflows when an error happens. I found this section of code on different sites but have not been able to get it to work. After stepping through the code I know the instancesEnum is empty. If it makes a difference, I'm working with SharePoint 2013 with a SharePoint 2010 workflow.

```
function test(){
var title; var workflow; var modified;
var listID = "672AF4F1-7160-4D93-B83B-2DA5C0F298B1";
var workflowID = "49DB5E25-E862-49DC-BE90-683B2AC9C6F8";


$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    listName: "My Testing",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
            workflow = $(this).attr("ows_TestCrea");
            modified = $(this).attr("ows_Modified");
            id =  parseInt($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
            if(workflow == 2){ //Using in progress instead of error for testing
                console.dir(title + " -" + workflow + " -" + modified + "  " + id);
                terminateWorkflow(listID,id ,workflowID);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

```
function terminateWorkflow(listId, itemId, subId){
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var workflowServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, context.get_web()); 
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
var wfInstances = workflowInstanceService.enumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, itemId);
context.load(wfInstances);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args){
        var instancesEnum = wfInstances.getEnumerator();
        while(instancesEnum.moveNext()){
            var instance = instancesEnum.get_current();
            if(instance.get_workflowSubscriptionId().toString() == subId){
                workflowInstanceService.terminateWorkflow(instance);
                context.executeQueryAsync(
                    function(sender, args){
                        console.log("Termination Successful");
                    },
                    function(sender,args){
                        console.log("Failed to terminate workflow.");
                        console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){
        console.log("Failed to load instances.");
        console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 2010 Workflows do make a difference.  Using "SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager" only works on SP2013 Workflows.  From what I understand, there isn't a "Stop Workflow" web service we can hit with 2010 Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

In my library I created a function that permits to stop a Workflow 2010 : https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#stopWorkflow

This technique uses an iframe to load the workflow page and trigger the "End the workflow" link, so you need to make sure the user has correct permissions, uses a browser and is on the same website (to avoid security errors).

That's the only way I found to stop a workflow 2010.

Comment: I have been attempting to use your library and I get the following error. Any ideas?

"unable yo get property '__doPostBack' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Open an issue on Github!